# Using Smack: login("foo", "bar") gives "Not connected to server" exception

Tags: xmpp, smack

I´m so sorry about this noob question, in my application I use a button to send a friend request, the other person accept it and it works fine, my problem is, when I want to delete a contact I got FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server.

The error is in this line

```
connection.login("113", "AA");
```

This is my code, I dont have any idea if this code works :(, can someone help me please?

```
 ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                "xxx.xxx.x.xx", 5222, "xxx.xxx.x.xx");
        XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

        SharedPreferences phoneNo3 = this.getSharedPreferences("phonef", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String  username = phoneNo3.getString("phonef", "");
        SharedPreferences conts = this.getSharedPreferences("contrass", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String  passwords = conts.getString("contrass", "");

        try {
        connection.login("113", "AA");

        RosterPacket packet = new RosterPacket();
        packet.setType(IQ.Type.SET);
        RosterPacket.Item item  = new RosterPacket.Item("laboral@xxx.xxx.x.xx", null);
        item.setItemType(RosterPacket.ItemType.remove);
        packet.addRosterItem(item);
        connection.sendPacket(packet);

        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to log in as " + username);
           connection.disconnect();
        }
```

Comment: From the message you get, it seems you are not connected to the server. It seems to be because your login failed. Did you investigate and check if the login is actually successful ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `connect()` before `login(String, String)`.

Comment: I chose this post because this was an recent post from you. The comment is irrelevant to the current question. I will remove it ASAP. I read some AOSP answers from you at stackexcahnge, I would like to contact you to get get your thoughts on android reverse tethering being an Host device and providing the internet over usb. I have been struggling to get real modification to make into AOSP code to achieve this. I would love to chat with you in private. I will remove this comment once I have established the communication with you.